# Keycloak permissions/claims per user, per project and per method

Tags: jwt, authorization, keycloak

We have users who buy market research projects. Every project has a set of statistical methods.
These methods are provided by different APIs. The **usage** of these methods is time limited (e.g. one time or multiple times a year).

Currently we **secure the calls** to these APIs via **JWT** and every request to an API is forwarded the our current self-made auth-API for verification.

I assume we need **fine grained claims** per **project** and **multiple JWT per user** - one for every project.

Can Keycloak handle such a requirement? I'm not sure about **what** is here the **resource** as we map resources not directly to users, but map them to projects and these projects belong to users.
Or is a project a resource?

Comment: Heya, not sure why you added the fusionauth tag, as the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with FusionAuth. What am I missing?

Comment: You are right, is removed.